# ruby/nokogiri scraping - export to multiple CSVs, then take columns from each and combine into final CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, export-to-csv

Ruby n00b here. I am scraping the same page twice - but in a slightly different way each time - and exporting them to separate CSV files. I would like to then combine the first column from CSV no.1 and the second column from CSV no.2 to create CSV no.3.

The code to pull CSVs no.1 & 2 works. But add my attempt to combine the two CSVs into the third one (commented-out at the bottom) returns the following error - the two CSVs populate fine, but the third stays blank and the script is in what appears to be an infinite loop. I know these lines shouldn't be at the bottom, but I can't see where else it would go...

```
alts.rb:45:in `block in <main>': undefined local variable or method `scrapedURLs1' for main:Object (NameError)
    from /Users/JammyStressford/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/csv.rb:1266:in `open'
    from alts.rb:44:in `<main>'
```

The code itself:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'   
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'


url = "http://www.example.com/page"
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))


CSV.open("results1.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  page.css('img.product-card-image').each do |scrape|
    product1 = scrape['alt']
    page.css('a.product-card-image-link').each do |scrape|
      link1 = scrape['href']

      scrapedProducts1 = "#{product1}"[0..-7]
      scrapedURLs1 = "{link1}"

      csv << [scrapedProducts1, scrapedURLs1]
    end
  end
end

CSV.open("Results2.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  page.css('a.product-card-image-link').each do |scrape|
    link2 = scrape['href']
    page.css('img.product-card-image').each do |scrape|
      product2 = scrape['alt']

      scrapedProducts2 = "#{product2}"[0..-7]
      scrapedURLs2 = "http://www.lyst.com#{link2}"

      csv << [scrapedURLs2, scrapedProducts2]
    end
  end
end

## Here is where I am trying to combine the two columns into a new CSV. ##
## It doesn't work. I suspect that this part should be further up...    ##

# CSV.open("productResults3.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  # csv << [scrapedURLs1, scrapedProducts2]
#end
puts "upload complete!"
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing your code and your question.  I hope my input helps!

- Your `scrapedURLs1 = "{link}"` and `scrapedProducts1 = "#{scrape['alt']}"[0..-7]` have a **1** on the end but you don't call it at `csv << [scrapedProducts, scrapedURLs]` **THIS IS THE ERROR YOU ARE GETTING**
- I would recommend combining your first two steps to skip
  writing to a file, but into an Array of Arrays and THEN you can write
  them to file.
- Do you realize that in the example code you've given
  `scrapedURLs1, scrapedProducts2` would be mixing the wrong urls to
  the wrong products.  Is that what you mean to do?
- Within the commented out code `scrapedURLs1, scrapedProducts2` do not exist, they have not been declared.  You need to open both files to read with `.each do |scrapedURLs1|` and then another with `.each do |scrapedProducts2|` and then those variable will exist because the `each` Enumerator instantiates them.

Reusing the same `|scrape|` variable on your inner iteration isn't a good idea.  Change the name to something else such as `|scrape2|` .  It "happens" to work because you've already taken what you need in `product=scrape['alt']` before the second loop.  If you rename the second loop variable you can move the `product=scrape['alt']` line into the inner loop and combine them.  Example:

```
# In your code example you may get many links per product.
# If that was your intent then that may be fine.
# This code should get one link per product.
CSV.open("results1.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  page.css('img.product-card-image').each do |scrape|
    page.css('a.product-card-image-link').each do |scrape2|
      #      [      product       ,     link       ]
      csv << [scrape['alt'][0..-7], scrape2['href']]
      # NOTE that scrape['alt'][0..-7] and scrape2['href'] are already strings
      # so you don't need to use "#{ }"
    end
  end
end
```

Side note: Ruby 2.0.0 does not need the line `require "rubygems"`

If you're working with CSVs I **highly recommend you using James Edward Gray II's faster_csv gem**.  See an example of usage here: https://github.com/JEG2/faster_csv/blob/master/examples/csv_writing.rb